# React Router nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, dropdown, nested-routes

I'm learning react by developing a simple app.

I've implemented a protecred route after login. Once loggedIn I'm redirected to the Hompage that present a navbar with two cascading dropdown and a sidebar with an accordion
Selecting the first dropdown the second is populated. Selecting the second dropdown the sidebar accordion is populated.
Everithing works but I have an issue I'm not able to solve

I have setted my route like this

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
    return ( 
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path = '/login' component={LogIn}/>
                <PrivateRoute path = '/' component={PPC} exact={true}/>
            </Switch>
        </>
     );
}
 
export default AppRoutes;
```

How can I manage further route within the private route? For axample I have a Component Main and a component Sidebar

Inside Sidebar I have Link to='/test'

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Feature = (props) => {
    const {data, selected, clicked} = props

    return ( 
        <Card.Body>
        {data.map(i => {
            return (
            <Link to='/test'
            // href="#"
            onClick={() => selected(i.id)}
            key={i.id}
            className={clicked === i.id ? 'sidemenu-2-level active' : 'sidemenu-2-level'}
            >
                {i.feature}
            </Link>
            )
        })}
        </Card.Body>
     )
}
 
export default Feature;
```

teh main is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import  "./style.main.css";
import Test from './test';
import PrivateRoute from '../../../routes/privateRoute'


    const Main = () => {
      
        return ( 
            <Row id='main'>
                <Col className='mainCol'>
                <PrivateRoute path = '/test' component={Test} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
         );
    }
     
    export default Main;
```

Basically I want the test component tobe rendered inside Main component
When I click on the link I get a white page.

How to manage it?

**EDIT**: Finally I got it. The issue was the exact into the private route. Removing that option now everything works

Comment: Code seems file. Would you share a live example using https://snack.expo.io/ or something like that!

Comment: sorry for that. it's a bit difficult to me to create a sandbox like that. I'l try but it require me a bit of time

Comment: I've review my question. Not able to reproduce everything in a sample